# How to load an iframe when scrolled to?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I have an animation in an iframe, but I don't want it to load until you scroll down to it. Is this possible? Thanks!

Comment: Modify the src of iframe whenever you want it to display on scroll, the iframe will reload itself. Also to hide it from being displayed you can put its src to some null value.

Comment: Using JavaScript/jquery it is possible but could cause issues with the delay of having to load it. You can also try a display:none and use Js/Jq to change the display

Comment: @KamleshKushwaha I didn't think about changing the source. I'll try that.

Answer (score 2):

You could try my project https://github.com/emn178/jquery-lazyload-any.
Lazyload youtube iframe demo: http://emn178.github.io/jquery-lazyload-any/samples/youtube/

Usage:

```
<div class=".lazyload">
  <!--
    <iframe src="xxx" />
  -->
</div>
<script>
  $('.lazyload').lazyload();
</script>
```